# can i integrate tree view in syncfusion document editor while clicking on button in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

I have created one custom button in syncfusion document editor tool bar and named it as tree view now. I want add that tree view functionality in document editor. is there any method to implemented tree view functionality in document editor of syncfusion. please help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

In a Word document, we can add only the predefined elements supported by Microsoft Word. Adding a custom control inside a Word document and binding the UI actions for that control is not feasible. Hence, this request can't be achieved in Microsoft Word and the Syncfusion Document Editor, either.

Alternate solutions that have been verified in the Syncfusion Document Editor are:

1. Add a button to the toolbar to open the treeview designer popup.
2. Create a popup to design the treeview component with insert and cancel buttons.
3. The insert button converts the designed treeview into an image and inserts it at the cursor position inside the Document Editor.

But, we determined that it is not possible to achieve your requirement using the Syncfusion Document Editor.

Reason: In syncfusion tree view, there is no option to get the tree view as an image. So, it is not possible to achieve this point "Insert button converts the designed treeview as image and inserts inside the Document editor at cursor position."